# What happens when pthreads wait in mutex_lock/cond_wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex

I have a program that should get the maximum out of my cpu.

It is multithreaded via pthreads that do their job well apart from the fact that they "only" get my cores to about 60% load which is not enough in my opinion.

I am searching for the reason and am asking myself (and hereby you) if the blocking functions mutex_lock/cond_wait are candidates?

What happens when a thread cannot run on in such a function?

- Does pthread switch to another thread it handles or
- does the thread yield its time to the system and if the latter is the case, can I change this behavior?

Regards,

Nobody

**More Information**
The setting is one mainthread that fills the taskpool and countless workers that fetch jobs from there and wait on a conditional that is signaled via broadcast when a serialized calculation is done. They go on with the values from this calculation until they are done, deliver their mail and fetch the next job...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a typical modern pthreads implementation, each thread is managed by the kernel not unlike a separate process.  Any blocking call like `pthread_mutex_lock` or `pthread_cond_wait` (but also, say, `read`) will yield its time to the system.  The system will then find another eligible thread to schedule, whether in your process or another process, and run it.

If your program is only taking 60% of the CPU, it is more likely blocked on I/O than on pthread operations, unless you have done something way too granular with your pthread operations.

Comment: So there is no way to have userspace multithreading with pthreads?

Comment: What operating system?  The old `LinuxThreads` implementation was entirely user-space.  (It also suffered from some unavoidable standards non-compliance.)  I believe Solaris uses (used?) a hybrid system where each kernel thread mapped to a bunch of user-space threads.  The real question is, why do you think you need this?  Going through the kernel on Linux, for instance, is almost as fast a a library call.

Comment: Also modern implementations optimize the "no contention" case to avoid making a system call at all.  I doubt this is the source of your performance problems.

Comment: Its designed to be as portable es possible but at least Linux/Windows. I wiped out the whole calculation for testing so it is just simulating and still runs on 60%.

Comment: @Nobody:  There is no standard pthread mechanism which allows user space scheduling.  If you really sure you want to do that, implement coroutines within your code.  However, if you don't have extensive experience with multi-threads and stack management there are better solutions.

Comment: It seems you were right with the granularity of my operations. I built bigger blocks and it runs faster. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread is waiting on a mutex/condition, it doesn't use resources (well, uses just a tiny amount). Whenever the thread enters waiting state, control switches to other threads. When the mutex is released (or condition variable signalled), the thread wakes up and may acquire the mutex (if no other thread grabs it first), and continue to run. If however some other thread acquires the mutex (this can happen if several threads are waiting for it), the thread returns to sleeping state.

Comment: It is totally clear for me that he is waiting, but it does not wait on the cpu, or does it? If it does not then some other thread should run there. So I ask you is it one of the same process or not?

Comment: What does "wait on cpu" mean? do you mean something like busy polling? usually, the implementation avoid it.

Comment: @Nobody - If the CPU is idle, all threads are waiting for something, like disk I/O or network traffic. Can you find something else to do at that moment?

Comment: I always have threads that are working without I/O, they are just calculating and accessing the RAM.

Comment: @Nobody: okay, if there is an active thread in the application, the OS almost always allocates the processor time for it. Mind that often the thread is bound to a single core, so if your processor is multicore, and application has only one active thread, it will take only 50% of maximal load.

Comment: It has actually 100 threads that I dont want to track one by one but which I want to execute. Only 6 of them are enabled at once so the processor should be used well without switching all the time.